# Convert Python Object into JSON-Object

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to send JsonResponse(convert python objects into JSON) to the HTML page. for that, I write a view like this:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

```
def send_json(request):

    data = [{'name': 'Peter', 'email': 'peter@example.org'},
            {'name': 'Julia', 'email': 'julia@example.org'},
            {'name': True, 'data': None}]

    a = JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return render (request, 'index.html', {'a' : data})
```

But, *It shows context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse.* error.

In HTML:

```
{{ a }}
```

Output:
[{'name': 'Peter', 'email': 'peter@example.org'}, {'name': 'Julia', 'email': 'julia@example.org'}, {'name': True, 'data': None}]

But I want to archive **null** instead of *None*, **true** instead of *True*. same as JSON objects. **without using DRF(Django-Rest-Framework)**.

Comment: `return render (request, 'index.html', {'a' : data})`

Comment: It coming like this:[{'name': 'Peter', 'email': 'peter@example.org'}, {'name': 'Julia', 'email': 'julia@example.org'}, {'name': True, 'data': None}] but I want None -> null, True -> true.